# How to define an address/cell location thats in a range

Tags: excel, vba, range, linear-interpolation

I am trying to write code that essentially performs linear interpolation for me and spits the result out into an email. I have set both the first column and top row as their own ranges (excluding 3300). Each require a user input of a number within each of the ranges. The interpolation is being performed against the top row. Currently I am using the Excel Lookup Worksheet Function to find the x1 for interpolation. My plan is to then use the address/cell location of x1 to get the remaining interpolation values required (x2, y1, y2) but I can't figure out how to define its location when its found with a variable.

Attached is a snippet of the table:
[image: Table of values]

I am attaching just the address related components of the code currently but if needed I can copy paste the whole function, thanks!

```
Dim avgSourceActivity As Double, ContainerActivity As Double, NumbSources As Integer
NumbSources = ws1.Range("D9").Value

'defining search ranges and variable locations
Dim avgSourceActRange As Range
Set avgSourceActRange = ws2.Range("h5:af5")
Dim numbSourcesRange As Range
Set numbSourcesRange = ws2.Range("G6:G19")
ws1.Range("D12").Value = avgSourceActivity

'searches the first column for the value of NumbSources
Dim FoundSourceNumb As Range
Set FoundSourceNumb = Range(numbSourcesRange).Find(NumbSources)
'establishes bounds of source activity for linear interpolation
Dim LookupFormulaMin As Double, LookupFormulaMax As Double
LookupFormulaMin = WorksheetFunction.Lookup(avgSourceActivity, avgSourceActRange)
MsgBox (LookupFormulaMin)

'write something in here to define LookUpFormulaMin's cell location
'use it to get the x2 by shifting over one in the cell range
LookupFormulaMax = ws2.Cells(LookupFormulaMin.Row, LookupFormulaMin.Column + 1).Value
MsgBox (LookupFormulaMax)
```

Comment: avgSourceActivity isn't given a value but used twice, were you meant to use `avgSourceActivity = ws1.Range("D12").Value` instead? As far as I know, you're also only going to get a value from the lookup, not the range so you wouldn't be able to use `.Row`/`.Column` on it, use [the .Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) instead (like you're using prior to it). If I misunderstood something, let me know.

Comment: Ah yes, avgSourceActivity is a calculated value which I forgot to include the snippet, that does not impact the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: The Find.Method will allow me to get a cell location that I can use for the LookupFormulaMax?

Comment: The Find method gives you a range reference which you should be able to use the `.Row` and `.Column` on, but I don't know what you wouldn't just be able to use `rng.Value` at that point since that seems what you're going for anyway. You'd be using the Find method on avgSourceActRange which is in the ws2 anyway.

Comment: While that is true for the source number, for the other values in interpolation, they are found by going down the specific number of rows from the source number (which is why I would use the address/location

Comment: I have tried each of the following and nothing shows up in the message box... I am not sure if its my syntax? If someone could help with that please

Comment: Dim FoundSourceNumb As Range
    Set FoundSourceNumb = Range(numbSourcesRange).Find(NumbSources)
    MsgBox ("test test test")
    MsgBox ("the source row is " & FoundSourceNumb.Row)
    MsgBox ("the source column is " & FoundSourceNumb.Column)
    MsgBox ("the source column is " & FoundSourceNumb.Address)

Comment: You don't need to use Range() around a range variable, just use the variable as is, i.e. `Set FoundSourcesNumb = numbSourcesRange.Find(NumbSources)`

Comment: both those work now, thanks @Notus_Panda!